# How to edit one column in a row of the database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to edit one column in a row of the database in laravel

I can't update one column of row has multiple columns by laravel

My edit :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $addremark=bookappoitment::findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin.ManageTime.addremarks', compact('addremark'));
}
```

My update:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
      'Remarks'=>'required'
    ]); 

    $data=bookappoitment::find($id);
    $data->Remarks = $request->get('Remarks');
    $data->save();

    return view('/home');
}
```

link to update:

```
<a href="{{route('BookAppoint.update',$addremark->id)}}">Update</a>
```

form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Remarks :</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="Remarks" placeholder="Remarks">{{ $addremark->Remarks }}</textarea>
      </div>

      <a class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord " href="{{route('BookAppoint.update',$addremark->id)}}">Update</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to update the remarks column?

Comment: yes just one column

Comment: Is it always the same column that you need to update?

Comment: Yes same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update 1 (or more, just add to the array) column through the `DB` class.

```
DB::table('yourTable')->where('id', $id)->update(['remarks' => $request->input('Remarks')]);
```

You can also do it for a model like so:

```
bookappoitment::where('id', $id)->update(['remarks' => $request->input('Remarks')]);
```

[It's in the Laravel documentation here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates)

---

```
<form class="" action="index.html" method="{{ route('BookAppoint.update', $addremark->id) }}">
  @method('PATCH')
  @csrf

  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Remarks">Remarks :</label>
          <textarea name="remarks" rows="10" placeholder="Remarks">{{$addremarks->Remarks}}</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">

    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much, sir, :)  but what about the update link   <a href="{{route('BookAppoint.update',$addremark->id)}}">Update</a>

Comment: Are you using that link to submit a form or something similar? What's not working about it?

Comment: Can you add your form to the post?

Comment: <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6"><div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Remarks :</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="Remarks" placeholder="Remarks">{{ $addremark->Remarks }}</textarea>
    </div>              
       <a class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord " href="{{route('BookAppoint.update',$addremark->id)}}">Update</a>
  </div>
     </div>
                        </div>

Comment: sure, I Update the post

Comment: I don't see a form tag in the code you posted. You should use it so you can submit the form with a normal submit button instead of a link. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, sir for your time you are a very good man :) Now I'll test the code thanks again